# Multiple applications crash on 17.10 with "Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xff" with samsung scannner

Tags: scanner, samsung, 17.10, sane, simplescan

I have a Samsung scanner which hasn't been working since I installed 17.10.

```
# sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3430 [SCX-5635 Series]) at libusb:001:002
```

Each time I try to use `simple-scan` on 17.10, I get a crash.

```
$ simple-scan 
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xff
```

Same error (crash) with `gscan2pdf`

```
$ gscan2pdf 
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xff
```

and same error with `xscanimage`

```
$ xscanimage 
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xff
```

I think `sane` doesn't use the right driver

```
# scanimage -L
device `xerox_mfp:libusb:001:002' is a Samsung Samsung SCX-5635 Series multi-function peripheral
```

I have installed the driver from the Samsung website.  New file `/etc/sane.d/smfp-samsung.conf` but seemingly the xerox driver is still being used.

In the `xerox_mfp.conf` there is well reference of the Samsung

So what's the problem? Bug in the xerox driver? Incorrect config?

Comment: `Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xff` should appear while trying to open a png file wrongly suffixed as jpg with some specific applications like "Eye of GNOME" (aka Image Viewer).

Comment: How long ago did you install 17.10 (did you start from beta2?)

Comment: it is the image from 10 days ago and I have applied all updates

Comment: I'm getting the same error with geany on a 17.10 upgrade from 17.04.
`  geany x.txt
    /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 1):

Not connected with the scanner, but I found this question through searching on the "murrine-scrollbar" error.

`/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant`

This seems to trigger when opening any gui program from the terminal.

As reported in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1724078/comments/4 , edit the mentioned file at line 30, replacing `murrine-scrollbar` with `scrollbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung "is" Xerox for some devices.
Do check if you are not affected by either:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012
or
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1707352
and don't forget to let people know that you are affected too.